# Source.actorRef not streaming to websocket with akka-stream

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I am trying to connect an `akka-stream` `Source` with a websocket.

```
object TestWebServer {

  val source1 = Source.actorRef[WsMessage](10, OverflowStrategy.dropHead)
    .map { case msg@WsMessage(a,b,c,d,e,f) => println("Received from stream" + msg);TextMessage(c) }

  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  val source2 = Source.tick(initialDelay = 0 second, interval = 1 second, tick = TextMessage("tick"))



  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    // needed for the future flatMap/onComplete in the end
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher


    val requestHandler: HttpRequest => HttpResponse = {
      case req@HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri.Path("/ws"), _, _, _) =>
        req.header[UpgradeToWebSocket] match {
          case Some(upgrade) => upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore, source1)
          case None => HttpResponse(400, entity = "Not a valid websocket request!")
        }
      case _: HttpRequest => HttpResponse(404, entity = "Unknown resource!")
    }


    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandleSync(requestHandler, "localhost", 8080)

    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
  }
}
```

Using a client such as `Simple Web Socket Client` (SWSC), I can see that

- if I connect the websocket with `source1`, 
  `upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore, source1)`
  I don't see anything back with SWSC
- if I connect the websocket with `source2`, 
  `upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore, source2)` I can see the message `tick` displayed in the SVSC console every 1 second (expected)

When I send a message to `source1`, I can see the message `Received from stream`. So I believe `source1` is set up correctly.

Does anyone know how I can make the `source1` behave like `source2` ? Something special to connect the `source1` to ?

Thank you

**Updated**:

- I have updated the code. I actually declared the 2 sources outside the `main` so that I can use it from another Actor System to send a message . 
  Is that the correct way to share the ref to send a message to `source1`  or should I use something like `actorSelection` or a variant?
- As Vladimir Matveev mentionned, I have tried :
  `source1.mapMaterializedValue { ref => ref ! WsMessage(..., "x", ...); ref ! WsMessage(..., "y", ...) }` but I still can not see the updates in SWSC

Here is the code of my test client:

```
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system2")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    // needed for the future flatMap/onComplete in the end
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val source1Client = TestWebServer.source1
    source1Client.mapMaterializedValue { ref => ref ! WsMessage(DateTime.now(), "x", "xx", 0, 0, 0); ref ! WsMessage(DateTime.now(), "y", "yy", 0, 0, 0) }

    val source11Client = TestWebServer.source1
    val actorRefClient = source11.to(Sink.ignore).run()
    actorRef2 ! WsMessage(DateTime.now(), "x", "xx", 0, 0, 0)

  }
}
```

- `source1` from the `Test` doesnt reach the `Source.actorRef` (`source1` in `TestWebServer`)
- `actorRefClient` does reach `source1` in `TestWebServer` in print out in the console `Received from streamWsMessage(...)`

Comment: Your code works correctly for me. Are you sure you're sending the messages to the correct actor? I did `mapMaterializedValue { ref => ref ! WsMessage(..., "x", ...); ref ! WsMessage(..., "y", ...) }` on the source and I can see `x` and `y` in the output of the websocket connection.

Comment: Vladimir, please see my updates - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but your updates do not help much. Here is an example program which runs fine for me, both when I use akka-http websockets client and when I use some external tool like [wsta](https://github.com/esphen/wsta/):

```
import java.time.Instant
import scala.io.StdIn

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.{TextMessage, UpgradeToWebSocket, WebSocketRequest}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}

case class WsMessage(a: Instant, b: String, c: String, d: Int, e: Int, f: Int)

object MainServer extends App {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  val source = Source.actorRef[WsMessage](10, OverflowStrategy.dropHead)
    .map {
      case msg@WsMessage(_, _, c, _, _, _) =>
        println(s"Received from stream: $msg")
        TextMessage(c)
    }
    .mapMaterializedValue { ref =>
      ref ! WsMessage(Instant.now(), "a", "x", 0, 0, 0)
      ref ! WsMessage(Instant.now(), "b", "y", 0, 0, 0)
    }

  val requestHandler: HttpRequest => HttpResponse = {
    case req@HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri.Path("/ws"), _, _, _) =>
      req.header[UpgradeToWebSocket] match {
        case Some(upgrade) => upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore, source)
        case None => HttpResponse(StatusCodes.BadRequest, entity = "Not a valid websocket request!")
      }
    case _ =>
      HttpResponse(StatusCodes.NotFound, entity = "Unknown resource!")
  }

  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandleSync(requestHandler, "localhost", 8080)

  println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
  StdIn.readLine()
  bindingFuture
    .flatMap(_.unbind())
    .onComplete(_ => actorSystem.terminate())
}

object MainClient extends App {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  Http()
    .singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest(Uri("ws://localhost:8080/ws")), Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.foreach(println), Source.empty))
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  actorSystem.terminate()
}
```

I do not see any important difference between this program and yours. This program also includes both the server and the client, so you can start the server and then start the client multiple times. For example, here is my server output after two client runs:

```
Server online at http://localhost:8080/
Press RETURN to stop...
Received from stream: WsMessage(2016-06-28T08:58:21.478Z,a,x,0,0,0)
Received from stream: WsMessage(2016-06-28T08:58:21.478Z,b,y,0,0,0)
Received from stream: WsMessage(2016-06-28T08:58:29.925Z,a,x,0,0,0)
Received from stream: WsMessage(2016-06-28T08:58:29.925Z,b,y,0,0,0)
```

And here is one of the clients output:

```
TextMessage.Strict(x)
TextMessage.Strict(y)
```

I see similar thing when I run `wsta ws://localhost:8080/ws`.

Also, it doesn't matter where you declare `Source`s, `Sink`s or `Flow`s: they are immutable blueprints which can only "act" when they are `run()`.

Comment: I can see now the messages printed out if I use your code. The only difference I see between my code and yours is that your source is sending the message from within the its definition. In my code I retrieved the `source` and I send a message to it (I basically want an external actor to send a message to the `source`). I think the problem could come from running the webserver in 1 JVM and I launch my test client in another JVM (different program). Could it be?

Comment: @ccheneson, what is your test client? In my example above there is `MainClient` object which is a separate application. Naturally, when I tested it working together with `MainServer`, they were started in separate JVMs.

Comment: @ccheneson, also, how exactly do you "retrieve" the source actor? I see no way to do it without `mapMaterializedValue` and storing it somewhere inside a `var` or something like it, which is naturally not very nice.

Comment: Sorry bad wording. By test client, I meant my program that sends a WsMessage to the `source`. I basically would like this: From an external actor, I want to send some `WsMessage` message to `source` that will stream those messages back tot he client via the websocketSorry bad wording. By test client, I meant my program that sends a WsMessage to the `source`. I basically would like this: From an external actor, I want to send some `WsMessage` message to `source` that will stream those messages back to the client (e.g. a web browser) via the websocket

Comment: That' s why I moved the `source` declaration outside the `main` so that I can import it from another place. I dont think its nice neither. If you have another idea on how to access `source` from the outside (`akka-remote`?), please let me know - Thanks

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the sending the message to the source happens in a different JVM from that where the materialized source lives? I'm not even sure how this could look. How do you even get the respective `ActorRef` in another JVM to send the message to? In general, sending messages between JVMs requires akka networking and/or cluster.

Comment: Yes you understand correctly. Probably I should look into akka-remote for this or another design. Thanks for your time.